# How to read data from JSON file and display in emulator using phonegap?

Tags: json, ajax, file, cordova

I am trying to display some JSON data which is available in a .json file in my application. The data is available through the web browser, but I am unable to get the data when it comes to emulator. Could some one help me in fixing this.

I used ajax call (getJSON) to retrieve the file.

```
$.getJSON('../files/english.json', function (data) {
            //using the data to display
        });
```

Comment: add some code for better responses

Answer (score 1):

To understand what the problem is, simply extend your code to get additional information.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON('../files/english.json', function (data) {
  //using the data to display
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
  console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

The `fail()` function will tell you where the problem is.
As far as I can see from these few information, the problem could be in the relative path.

Please also note that, according to the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the
>   request will usually fail silently.